# How to use a pre-populated database from assets using floor in flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, floor

I am new in Flutter and couldn't find any documentation about my question. Have you any suggestion?

Comment: I have used floor and I have a question regarding your use case. Does your pre populated database also have associated "db.g.dart" and "db.dart" files? I'd like to understand better what you mean by pre-populated database. Can you share any related code snippets

Comment: Did you get any solution for your problem?